# Coin change algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming, change-making-problem

I've implemented the coin change algorithm using Dynamic Programming and Greedy Algorithm w/ backtracking. The description is as follows:

> Given an amount of change (n) list all of the possibilities of coins that can be used to satisfy the amount of change

It would be nice to have a code review to show me where I can improve on readability (along with other things you may find!). I've been trying to clean it up and refactor a bit, but a fresh set of eyes would be nice. I went a bit crazy on comments because I wanted to make sure I would be able to look at this in a few months and not forget why I did something the way I did. But perhaps putting some of that info in a github wiki would have been better.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * Given an amount of change (n) list all of the possibilities of coins that can
 * be used to satisfy the amount of change.
 * 
 * Example: n = 12
 * 
 * 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
 * 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,5
 * 1,1,5,5
 * 1,1,10
 * 
 * @author Eric
 *
 */
public class CoinChange {
    private int[] coins = { 1, 5, 10, 25 };

    /**
     * Uses a greedy algorithm with backtracking to find the
     * possible combinations
     * 
     * @param sum - the sum of the current combination
     * @param n - the target
     * @param pos - position for which coin to start at
     * @param combination - the current combination
     */
    public void findPossibleCombinations(int sum, int n, int pos, List<Integer> combination) {
        // Begin at pos. We use pos so that we don't have duplicate combinations
        // in different orders ex: 1,1,10 is the same as 1,10,1 or 10,1,1
        // This is possible because when we are at a larger coin, we know that
        // combinations with smaller coins and the larger/current coin
        // have already been found, so we no longer need to consider them.
        // If we did consider them, we would have duplicates.
        // Therefore, pos allows you to only look ahead at larger coins,
        // ignoring smaller coins
        for (int i = pos; i < coins.length; i++) {
            int coin = coins[i];
            sum += coin; // Add the coin to the sum

            // If the sum is larger than n, then we have reached an invalid
            // combination.
            if (sum > n) {
                return;
            }

            combination.add(coin); // Add the coin to the current combination

            // If the sum is equal to n, then we have reached a valid
            // combination. Return from the recursive call
            // because any continuation would be unnecessary as adding more
            // coins or a larger coin would cause the sum to be larger than n.
            if (sum == n) {
                System.out.println(combination);
                combination.remove(combination.size() - 1);
                return;
            }

            findPossibleCombinations(sum, n, pos, combination);

            // Remove the last coin
            combination.remove(combination.size() - 1);
            sum -= coin; // remove the coin from the sum
            pos++;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Uses dynamic programming to find the possible combinations
     * 
     * @param n - the target
     * @return
     */
    public List<List<Integer>> findPossibleCombinationsDP(int n) {
        /**
         * Cell is a class to represent each cell in the n*m grid
         * 
         * @author Eric
         *
         */
        class Cell {
            // All of the possible combinations at each cell
            private List<List<Integer>> combinations = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

            List<List<Integer>> getCombinations() {
                return combinations;
            }

            void setCombinations(List<List<Integer>> combinations) {
                this.combinations = combinations;
            }

            void addCombination(List<Integer> combination) {
                if (combination != null) {
                    combinations.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(combination));
                }
            }

        }

        // Create the grid
        Cell[][] sol = new Cell[coins.length + 1][n + 1];

        // Create new cells for the boundary values
        for (int i = 0; i < coins.length + 1; i++) {
            sol[i][0] = new Cell();
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < n + 1; i++) {
            sol[0][i] = new Cell();
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < coins.length + 1; i++) {
            int coin = coins[i - 1];
            for (int j = 1; j < n + 1; j++) {
                Cell cell = new Cell();

                Cell prevCoinCell = sol[i - 1][j];
                // Copy the combinations
                cell.setCombinations(prevCoinCell.getCombinations());

                if (j == coin) {
                    // Only need to add the coin as a combination by itself in this case
                    cell.addCombination(new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(coin)));
                } else if (coin < j) {
                    // In this case we need to get the previous cell minus the
                    // size of the coin. Each combination needs to have
                    // the current combination added to it
                    Cell prevCell = sol[i][j - coin];
                    for (List<Integer> prevCombination : prevCell.getCombinations()) {
                        List<Integer> combination = new ArrayList<Integer>(prevCombination);
                        combination.add(coin);
                        cell.addCombination(combination);
                    }
                }
                sol[i][j] = cell;
            }
        }
        return sol[coins.length][n].getCombinations();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CoinChange cc = new CoinChange();
        int n = 21;
        List<List<Integer>> combinations = cc.findPossibleCombinationsDP(n);
        System.out.println("Possible Combinations using Dynamic Programming");
        for(List<Integer> combination : combinations){
            System.out.println(combination);
        }
        System.out.println("\nPossible Combinations using Greedy Algorithm with Backtracking");
        cc.findPossibleCombinations(0, n, 0, new ArrayList<Integer>());
    }

}
```

Comment: great attempt. my criticism (without offering a solution just yet) - is that it is certainly not very readable and understandable. it should be an easy read.

Answer (score 3):

After 6 months still not having an answer on codereview is probably a good sign.
Meaning nobody sees any major problems with your code and can't be bothered with the small things.

Perhaps getting this answer could be a good time to review your own code and see what you would do differently now yourself.

The only thing that I can say is "wrong" with this code is your choice of variable names and then the reason for adding lots of comments.

Most of your comments are actually well placed. More specifically those explaining WHY you do something. Especially the importance of your ordering of coins from small to large.

Some of the comments like this one:

```
combination.add(coin); // Add the coin to the current combination
```

are kinda useless if you would choose better variable names (although combination isn't really that bad either).

So my only real change would be from

```
public void findPossibleCombinations(
        int sum, int n, int pos, List<Integer> combination) {
```

to

```
public void findPossibleCombinations(
        int currentTotal, 
        int targetAmmount, 
        int currentCoinIndex, 
        List<Integer> currentChange) {
```

Or even better names if you can find them. Which hopefully makes some of your comments redundant.

Comment: thumbs up for the comment explanation... and yes, there's people, like me, who get waaaay too angry when they see stuff like `sum += coin; // Add the coin to the sum` :P